# about facebook Game Request how can I get the data when my app launcher

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how can I to do get the data("world") when my app launcher in Activity

```
GameRequestContent content = new GameRequestContent.Builder()
                     .setMessage("hello")
                     .setData("world")
                     .build();
             GameRequestDialog g = new GameRequestDialog(getActivity());
             g.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<GameRequestDialog.Result>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(GameRequestDialog.Result o) {
                     Log.i("onSuccess", new Gson().toJson(o.getRequestRecipients()));
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onCancel() {
                     Log.i("onSuccess", "onCancel");
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                     Log.i("onError", error.getMessage());
                     error.printStackTrace();
                 }
             });
             g.show(content);
```

Comment: could this be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596539/retrieve-game-request-data-when-receiving ?

Comment: Did you get any news? I need to know this too